# C++ opening a window without libraries

Tags: c++, user-interface, assembly, operating-system, window

I am new to C++, and I would like to know for future reference:

Is it possible to open a (cross-platform compatible) window without any libraries (such as Win32 API, GTK, QT, etc)?

If not, can someone explain why?

And how can an OS launch a GUI? Even if it does so with assembly, C++ can do what assembly can do (from what I know, tell me if I'm mistaken).

I have found a post about the same topic, but all the answers were saying that you cannot avoid the APIs, but they didn't mention why?

[C++ How do you make a simple window without the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925151/)

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it possible to create a GUI without API calls, or any external libraries?
2. If not, why, and how does an OS launch the GUI?
3. Can C++ do everything that assembly can do? (I don't really care about that since I think I can find the answer on Google, if someone answers though then I am grateful).

Comment: ***is it possible to create a GUI without API calls or any external libraries?*** No. `c++` has no concept of a GUI in the language.

Comment: @drescherjm do you know of a good book about it? (i'll search on anyway but if you can give name one i'd be grateful)

Comment: If it is a modern OS and not on an embedded system the OS will have device drivers that communicate with the GPU or graphics hardware. Then you have other software that communicates with these device drivers or the OS. Some of this may be directX, opengl, vulkan...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to create a GUI without API calls, or any external libraries?

No <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1: unless, for example, you are writing your own display driver and have direct access to video hardware.</sup>

> 2. If not, why

Every OS handles UI programming differently.  You must use the UI APIs that are provided by each OS that your program runs on (ie, Win32 on Windows, etc).  There is no common UI framework built into C++, so if you want to write a cross-platform UI then you will have to use a 3rd party library (ie, Qt, GTK, etc), or write your own, that wraps each OS-specific API into a common interface for your code to use.

> how does an OS launch the GUI?

It doesn't.  It just executes your program, nothing more.  The program then decides what to do at runtime.  If the program wants to display a GUI, then it has to call into the OS-provided UI APIs as needed.

> 3. Can C++ do everything that assembly can do?

More or less, yes <sup>2</sup>.  C++ is a compiled language that produces machine code that runs directly on the CPU, same as Assembly does. Also, many C++ compilers actually support the ability to embed actual Assembly instructions directly in the C++ code.  C++ does not use an intermediate bytecode that has to be translated into machine code at runtime, like scripting/interpreted languages use.

<sup>2: Not all CPU instructions can be executed directly, the OS will intervene if your program tries to execute an instruction that the OS doesn't want you to have access to (for example, instructions for direct hardware access).</sup>

Comment: For this question, there *are* important things you can do with asm that you can't do with C++.  The answer to 3. is No. In asm, you could use an instruction like `syscall` (on x86-64 for example) to invoke the OS's APIs directly.  For example on x86-64 GNU/Linux, opening a GUI window would normally involve libX11 making `socket` / `connect` and `read`/`write` system calls by calling into the wrapper functions in libc.  You could re-implement all that yourself in asm (or with some asm wrappers for the lowest level stuff) if you wanted.  It wouldn't be *portable*, but assembly inherently isn't.

Comment: Or on Windows, https://github.com/j00ru/windows-syscalls has reverse-engineered call numbers of system calls on various builds of Windows.  (Unlike Linux, Windows doesn't expose a stable system-call ABI to user-space so the call numbers can change between versions, or even between builds of the same version.  The supported Windows way is to call into the DLLs.)